# 'props' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie in react ,sorry if I don't post in a good place
In my script I just want to pass a array in a coponant in other coponant (sorry for my english)
My code

```js
class  ListItem extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
}
    render() {
    // Correct! There is no need to specify the key here:
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
    }
  

}
class NumberList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
}
   render() {
    
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    // Correct! Key should be specified inside the array.
    <ListItem key={number.toString()}
              value={number} />
   );
  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}
}
// ========================================
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: this is probably unrelated but since you are starting new, best to avoid this, old way of state management. I am also newbie. try and use hooks way of dealing with state.

Answer (score 0):

In **class component** you excess props though the class instance:

```
// not props.numbers
const numbers = this.props.numbers;
```

---

```
class ListItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <li>{this.props.value}</li>;
  }
}
class NumberList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const numbers = this.props.numbers;
    const listItems = numbers.map((number) => (
      <ListItem key={number.toString()} value={number} />
    ));
    return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the render() function of both components `props` is an instance variable. In order to get the props you need to do:

```
class ListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <li>{this.props.value}</li>;
  }
}
```

You could even [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) your props:

```
class ListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    return <li>{value}</li>;
  }
}
```

Same goes with the other component. Also, one thing to note. You could use [function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) instead of class components and not need to have your props as an instance variable:

```
function ListItem({ value }) {
  return <li>{value}</li>;
}
```

The above can replace your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you so much !!!
The two solutions are working :)
but one question is it possible to pass an array like that
class myComponantParent{
myArray[]

}
Class myComponantChildren{
display myArray

}
?
So to pass a array from one componant to an other componant without declared
the array before ReactDom but declaring the array in the parent componant to display it en a children componant

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes of course it is possible. I'll post a new answer answering this

Comment: Also, you need to mark an answer as a solution to your question.

Comment: Mark one of them as the valid one so that this question does not remain unanswered :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables from the parent component to the child component like so:

```
function ChildComponent({ array }) {
  if (!array || arr.length === 0) {
    return <p>No array was passed</p>
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {array.map((value, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          {value}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

function ParentComponent() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3]
  return <ChildComponent array={arr} />
}
```